# AVR C Function works from Main but not from other Function

Tags: c, avr

My friend and I are working on a project which involves programming an attiny48.
We're coding in Atmel Studio 6.2.

Just to get our feet wet in C and embedded programming we're trying to make an LED flash. Here is the code we have so far:

**User.h**

```
ifndef USER_H_
#define USER_H_

#include <avr/io.h>

// # Defines

#define F_CPU 1000000UL

// Function Prototypes
extern void Delay_Ms(uint16_t ms);
extern void Init(void);

extern uint8_t Check_Infrared(void);
extern void Toggle_PC0 (void);
#endif /* USER_H_ */
```

**User.c**

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <delay.h>
#include "User.h"

void Delay_Ms(uint16_t ms)
{
    uint32_t Delay_Cycles;


    for (Delay_Cycles = (ms * (F_CPU/10000)) ; Delay_Cycles > 0 ; Delay_Cycles--);
}

void Init(void)
{
    // Define Output Pins
    DDRC = DDRC |(1<<DDC0); // PC0 is digital output

    while(1)
    {
        PINC = (1<<PINC0); // Toggle PC0, This is the LED we have connected
        //_delay_ms(1000);  This is the builtin Delay which works here
        Delay_Ms(1000);  //we have established that this fails
    }
}
```

**Main.c**

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include "User.h"

int main(void)
{
    Init();
    while(1)
    {
        PINC = (1<<PINC0); // Toggle PC0
        Delay_Ms(1000);  //if we let it get here, it works!
    }
}
```

So what's happening is: The main() calls the function Init(), where we have copied the while loop that is supposed to flash the LED. Here, it does NOT work.
If we comment out the while(1) loop in the Init() function, the while(1) loop that is in the main() runs and the LED flashes.

We've played with the code and established that the Delay_Ms(ms) works when called from the main(), but not when called from the Init(). We suspect that this has something to do with the order of definition, defs, the includes or the header files, but as inexperienced C programmers we are a little lost.

We could just use the built in delay function but then this problem may come up elsewhere, in the future!

Any tips appreciated!

Comment: When the control passes to init(), it runs its own while loop which does not stop since you put it into an unending loop. Try removing the while from there. And just put the contents of it outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Delay_Ms()` function will not work the way you expect it to. If optimizations are not enabled, the inner loop compiles to about 20 instructions, so it will run considerably slower than expected. If optimizations are enabled, though, the entire loop is optimized away, causing the delay to disappear entirely. (The whole function literally just ends up compiling to a single `ret` instruction!)

Use the builtin `_delay_ms()`; it's calibrated correctly, and will not disappear under optimization.

Comment: +1. I was just about to post this, you can see it from the generated assembly that the loop goes away entirely. Simply sticking ```__asm__("nop");``` in the for loop stops the optimisation, but the timing will still be nowhere near accurate. Although I am not sure how it worked at all from ```main()```.

Comment: The question bothering me is why it works in main, but not when it is refactored out to another file. My educated guess is, maybe the compiler is able to optimise it away when Delay_Ms() it is called from within the same file (in User.c), but when it is being called across files (from main.c), the compiler doesn't know to optimize it. (It needs to generate references for the linker to link together).

Comment: Inserting the 'nop' ended up solving the problem.
We were going to use the built in delay anyway, we just figured it's better now to learn what was going wrong than be banging our heads against a wall later! Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

may I suggest this approach?

```
void Delay_Ms(uint16_t ms)
{
    while(ms--){
        _delay_ms(1);//built in util/delay.h
    }
}
```

it'll lose some accuracy over time (maybe 1us per ms), but this way you can use a delay with bigger values (that I suspect you realize you can't with _delay_ms directly)

if you want accurate delays you'll need to implement them with timers...

Answer (score 0):

I think your toggle code is wrong.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{

   while(1)
   {
       PORTC ^= (1<<PINC0); // Toggle PC0
       _delay_ms(1000);  //This will work!
   }
}
```

This code work for me.